# How to convert GeoCoordinate to Pushpin Location in C#?

Tags: c#, location, pushpin

I'm trying to make a pushpin for my current location, the examples I could find online all give me the same error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate' to 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location'.

Here is the code segment;

```
            GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            GeoCoordinate looc = watcher.Position.Location;
            Pushpin piin = new Pushpin();
            piin.Location = looc; //error here
```

I'm using XAML and Bing maps if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new Location object for the pushpin, populating it with the latitude/longitude of the GeoCoordinate object.
Note that the WPF control is old and no longer updated. If you're developing a new application it's recommended to use the UWP map control which can handle GeoCoordinate directly.